# Does any closed subset of the open unit circle have a circumscribing square, each of whose sides meets the subset?

Tags: geometry

> Let $A$ be a closed part of the plane (with its usual Euclidean distance from the usual scalar product), not empty and such that all its elements are at a distance less than $1$ of the origin. Prove the existence of a square such that:
>
> 1. All elements of $A$ are in this square
> 2. Each side of the square meets $A$
>
> The square can be reduce to a point.

I can't found any counter-example to this mysterious assertion.

---

**Example:** If $A$ is the union of the triangle $T$ and point $A$

[image]

an answer is

[image]

Comment: What does the extra "The square can be reduced to a point" mean? Is that just to cover the case of a single point?

Comment: Wouldn't that just be a square exactly circumscribing the limiting circle of an open disc? Or am I misinterpreting your question? Also, what's so "mysterious" about the assertion? What's the source of the claim or question?

Comment: yes, A can be reduced to a single point

Comment: Deepak  I added an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $\ \theta\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]\ $ let
\begin{align}
x_+(\theta)&=\sup\{x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta\,|\,(x,y)\in A\}\\
x_-(\theta)&=\inf\{x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta\,|\,(x,y)\in A\}\\
y_+(\theta)&=\sup\{x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta\,|\,(x,y)\in A\}\\
y_-(\theta)&=\inf\{x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta\,|\,(x,y)\in A\}\ .
\end{align}
Then $\ x_+,x_-,y_+,y_-\ $ are continuous functions with
\begin{align}
x_+(0)&=y_+\textstyle{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\\
x_-(0)&=y_-\textstyle{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\\
y_+(0)&=x_+\textstyle{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\\
y_-(0)&=x_-\textstyle{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\ .
\end{align}
If $\ x_+(0)-x_-(0)=y_+(0)-y_-(0)\ $, then the rectangle with corners $\ \left(x_-(0),y_-(0)\right)\ $, $\ \left(x_+(0),y_-(0)\right)\ $, $\ \left(x_-(0),y_+(0)\right)\ $ and $\ \left(x_+(0),y_+(0)\right)\ $ is a square with the specified properties.

If $\ x_+(0)-x_-(0)<y_+(0)-y_-(0)\ $, then
\begin{align}
x_+\textstyle{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}-x_-\textstyle{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}&=y_+(0)-y_-(0)\\
&>x_+(0)-x_-(0)\\
&=y_+\textstyle{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}-y_-\textstyle{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\ ,
\end{align}
or if $\ x_+(0)-x_-(0)>y_+(0)-y_-(0)\ $, then
\begin{align}
x_+\textstyle{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}-x_-\textstyle{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}&=y_+(0)-y_-(0)\\
&<x_+(0)-x_-(0)\\
&=y_+\textstyle{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}-y_-\textstyle{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\ .
\end{align}
It therefore follows from the intermediate value theorem that there exists $\ \theta^*\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\ $ such that $\ x_+\left(\theta^*\right)-x_-\left(\theta^*\right)=y_+\left(\theta^*\right)-y_-\left(\theta^*\right)\ $.  The rectangle with corners
\begin{align}
&\left(x_-\left(\theta^*\right)\cos\theta^*+y_-\left(\theta^*\right)\sin\theta^*, -x_-\left(\theta^*\right)\sin\theta^*+y_-\left(\theta^*\right)\cos\theta^*\right),\\
&\left(x_+\left(\theta^*\right)\cos\theta^*+y_+\left(\theta^*\right)\sin\theta^*, -x_-\left(\theta^*\right)\sin\theta^*+y_-\left(\theta^*\right)\cos\theta^*\right),\\
&\left(x_-\left(\theta^*\right)\cos\theta^*+y_-\left(\theta^*\right)\sin\theta^*, -x_+\left(\theta^*\right)\sin\theta^*+y_+\left(\theta^*\right)\cos\theta^*\right),\\
&\left(x_+\left(\theta^*\right)\cos\theta^*+y_+\left(\theta^*\right)\sin\theta^*, -x_+\left(\theta^*\right)\sin\theta^*+y_+\left(\theta^*\right)\cos\theta^*\right)
\end{align}
is then a square with the specified properties.

**What's going on here?**

The set
$$
A(\theta)=\{(x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta,x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta)\,|\,(x,y)\in A\,\}
$$
is a congruent image of $\ A\ $ obtained by rotating it anticlockwise about the origin through an angle $\ \theta\ $. The points $\ (x_-(\theta),y_-(\theta))\ $,$\ (x_+(\theta),y_-(\theta))\ $,$\ (x_-(\theta),y_+(\theta))\ $ and $\ (x_+(\theta),y_+(\theta))\ $ are the corners of a rectangle with sides parallel to the coordinate axes and (apart from not necessarily being a square) having the desired properties with respect to the set $\ A(\theta)\ $.  The argument above shows that for some $\ \theta^*\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\ $ this rectangle *is* a square having the desired properties with respect to the set $\ A\left(\theta^*\right)\ $.  Rotating this square *clockwise* about the origin through the angle $\ \theta^*\ $ gives you a square which has the desired properties with respect to $\ A\ $.

Comment: lonza leggiera Thanks,  I'll take my time to understand this solution

Comment: This could be expressed in terms of [support functions](https://swt.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/SS2012/hs-seminar/Resources/papers/Ghosh-Support-Functions).

Comment: I've now added an outline of the basic ideas used in the proof which may be helpful in understanding it.

Comment: lonza leggiera   thanks for the addition

Comment: Have you heard about support functions ? I think it would help to simplify your explanations....

Comment: I've only ever come across them  in the study of convex analysis, and that was so long ago that I had forgotten their precise definition.  I suspect you're correct that I could have simplified the proof by using them.  However,  to achieve a degree of simplification that would satisfy me, I believe it would now take *me* too much effort to make it worthwhile trying to change  the answer.  By all means feel free to edit the answer yourself (or add your own).  I would be interested in seeing how much simplification could be achieved.

Comment: @lonza leggiera Thanks for you answer. I wasn't aware of it because you hadn't prefixed it by my pseudo. I will attempt to do it in the future.